# What interpretations of a change are supported by git commands?

Tags: git

I understand that git tracks changes of a project as a whole instead of particular files. That leads me to following question.

Can I use git commands to apply different interpretations of a change?

I might be asking "Which commit last modified this particular line?" or "Which commit modified that line's content but not removed identical content from somewhere else?".

What interpretations can I get out of the box and how? Which is default?

Comment: I was following your post until "I might also" and then you lost me.  You might want to edit to clarify things.

Comment: see the documents for `git log` and look at -G and -S and --follow options, and you also have `git gui blame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the fact that git is tracking the project as a whole is often misunderstood. What it means is that

- a commit, as a reproducible snapshot, always refers to the whole project
- git does not store individual file histories in separate files like RCS

But git still stores data in file-size units, called blob objects. A blob is just the contents of a file at a time, detached from its name, which is stored in a tree object.

An implication of this storage method is that file renames are not (always) explicit but implied:

```
git mv foo.c bar.c
cp foo.c bar.c; git add bar.c; git rm foo.c
```

The two lines above result in exactly the same `git status` output:

```
renamed: foo.c -> bar.c
```

Git simply detects that the identical blob object is referred to under a different name in a tree object.

Finally, as @AndrewC pointed out, `git log` has certain options to follow content.

```
git log --follow <single-file>  # Print the history of a file, following renames as well
git log -S string  # Show commits where the occurrence number of string has changed
git log -G string  # Show commits whose diff contains the string
```